# variance as an input for gaussian process regression (fitrgp) function in matlab

Tags: matlab, regression, variance, gaussian-process

I am using Gaussian process regression function in Matlab (fitrgp) and I already read the full documentation of this function. I work with time series data-set and each point in this data-set has it's own variances. I want to know if there is any way in order to pass both data points and variances to this function to specify the uncertainty among data or not?

this is the code I use:

```
trainNumber = 2000;
gprMdTrain  = fitrgp(xH1(1:trainNumber,:),yH1(1:trainNumber,:),...
'KernelFunction','squaredexponential','FitMethod','sd',...
'Standardize',1,'Verbose',1,'SigmaLowerBound',0.05);
[YpredTest,~,ci]   = predict(gprMdTrain,xH1(trainNumber+1:end,:));
[label,score,cost] = resubPredict(gprMdTrain);
```